# Build League Table and Show Position

Tags: sql, sql-server

This has me stumped.  This is quite a simplified version but let's say I have a league table of users in SQL Server such as:

```
UserId Total  
1       10  
2        5  
3       20  
4        3  
5       40  
6       15  
7       22  
8        1  
9       18  
10      33
```

Now I can easily order this to be by total like so:

```
Position  UserId  Total  
1            5      40  
2           10      33  
3            7      22   
4            3      20   
5            9      18   
6            6      15  
7            1      10  
8            2       5  
9            4       3   
10           8       1
```

But I would also like to display a particular users position in the table and the two above and below like so for user 1 who is seventh:

```
Position UserId  Total  
5           9      18   
6           6      15  
7           1      10  
8           2       5  
9           4       3
```

I hope this makes sense and any help/insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Total DESC) AS Position, 
          UserId, 
          Total
   FROM your_table) p
WHERE p.Position BETWEEN desiredId-2 AND desiredId+2
```

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` needs the `OVER` clause, otherwise it won't run. In this case, the `ORDER BY Total DESC` should be inside that `OVER`

Comment: @Lamak: yes, you're definitely right, I missed that. Thanks :)

Comment: Cheers guys, I was hoping there was a way for a single select but I think looking at this it has confirmed I will need to do a select to get the position of the user and then another select using the example you have placed above.  Many thanks, I'll take this as the best solution.